# Экземпляр объекта

Tags: c#, .net

В данном коде:

```
public class MyClass
    {
        public int x, y;
    }

    public static MyClass[,] array = new MyClass [ 3 , 3 ];

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i=0;i!=2 ;i++ )
        {
            for (int i2=0; i2!=2 ;i2++ )
            {
                array[i, i2].x = 3;
            }
        }
    }
```

вываливается на строчке присвоения с ошибкой "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.". Мне так и не успели рассказать в чем проблема, но я понимаю что проблема где-то в объявлении массива. msdn не помог. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: `!(i==2)` наверно `i!=2` лучше

Comment: Спасибо, поправил

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вы объявили массив объектов, но не проинициализировали их.

Чуть-чуть противоречит правилам, но так будет правильно:

```
public class MyClass
{
    // автоматическая реализации свойств(геттеров и сеттеров)
    public int X{get;set;}
    public int Y{get;set;}

    // конструктор класса 
    public MyClass(int x=0, int y=0)// с параметрами по умолчанию
    {
            X = x;
            Y = y;
    }
}

public static MyClass[,] array = new MyClass [ 3 , 3 ];

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    for (int i=0; i!=2 ;i++ )
    {
        for (int i2=0; i2!=2 ;i2++ )
        {
            array[i, i2] = new MyClass(3);
        }
    }
}
```

- [Автоматически реализуемые свойства](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb384054.aspx)
- [Именованные и необязательные аргументы](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd264739.aspx)

**UPD:** обновил ответ

Comment: интересное объявление цикла for , !(i==2)    Для меня проще i<2

Comment: это копипаста с вопроса, я здесь не при чём=)

Comment: Я, к сожалению, глупый и недалекий. Для меня ваше объявление класса выглядит пугающе сложно. Не могли бы вы объяснить мне что это такое?

Comment: а не проще ли было написать :
for (int i2=0; i2!=2 ;i2++ )
                {
                    array[i, i2] = new MyClass();
                    array[i, i2].x = 3;
                }

Comment: записи идентичны, ваша тоже будет работать, но конструктор с параметрами по умолчанию:

    public MyClass(int x=0, int y=0){...}

упрощает запись на одну строку кода, но при этом не увеличивает сложность его восприятия

Comment: Это пока пугающе сложно, потом в ООП углубишься, это для тебя будет просто как сходить в туалет))))

Comment: @semenvx27 это что получается, объектно-ориентированное программирование -- разновидность интеллектуальной дефекации? Однако...

Comment: @alexz, Давайте не будем придераться к словам?